# zoom css property doesn't applied on Mac safari browser

Tags: css, macos, safari

I have used gulp.spritesmith to generate sprite image and css. I have retina images which needs to be zoom by .5 to display correctly. It works perfectly fine on all browsers and devices except the Mac Safari. It doesn;t work on Mac safari when icon class is child of anchor tag. Following are code details.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WNSLrTeZCVQSk1Ex2mTj?p=preview

Following work

```
<div>
      <span class="rating-50"></span>
</div>
```

Following doesn't work

```
<a href="#">
      <span class="rating-50"></span>
</a>
```

Following is class details which does the icon scaling.

```
.rating-50{
zoom:.5;
-moz-transform:scale(.5);
-moz-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

I did some research and found that -webkit-transform: scale(.5); works on Mac Safari however since my code is already having zoom:.5 therefore image gets scaled down twice. 
Please go through the running pluker and help to find out the root cause and suggest some solution.

Comment: Running Safari 8 on Yosemite and the stars look exactly the same for both the <div> and <a> before and after the webkit scale is applied. If the <div> works for you but the <a> doesn't, try setting your <a> to display:block, since a div by default is block and an <a> by default is inline - this could be playing into it.

Comment: thanks, but display:block is not working. I am surprised that its working for you, my team and myself has Mac Yosemite and Safari 8 and its not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari doesn't support the IE-proprietary `zoom` CSS property.

There's a few different approaches. If it's background image you want to scale, use the CSS `background-size` property to specify how large the image should be in virtual pixels (or use `100% 100%` to fill the element!).

If it's an arbitrary element, you can use…

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);
```

…to scale it.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Used transform:scale() and it worked for all browsers smoothly.